# Sum of hypergeometric functions, variable number of arguments

Tags: special-functions, summation

How can I write in *Mathematica* an expression like this?

$$\sum_{k=1}^n {_{k}F_{k}} (1,1,\dots,1; \,2,2,\dots,2; \,z) ~,$$

where ${_{p}F_{q}}$ is the [generalized hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html).

My problem is that I don't know how to use *variable number of arguments*, which depends on a parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to `ConstantArray[]`, not much effort is needed:

```
mysum[n_Integer, z_] :=
   Sum[HypergeometricPFQ[ConstantArray[1, k], ConstantArray[2, k], z], {k, 1, n}]
```

Test:

```
mysum[3, z]
   (-1 + E^z)/z + HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, z] +
   (-EulerGamma - Gamma[0, -z] - Log[-z])/z
```

Comment: `Table[1, k]` and `Table[2, k]` are slightly more compact.